# How to hide current breadcrumb in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs

There is breadcrumbs on product page and product title just below them. It's too much for one line and I want to hide current crumb like this:

> Home->Catalog->Category->Subcategory->
>   H1 Product Title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php the part for $crumb. All is a link, but last is a simple text.

```
foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

    echo $before;

    if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo esc_html( $crumb[0] ); // Just replace $crumb here for empty ''
    }

    echo $after;

    if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo $delimiter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add This CSS in Your Active theme.

```
.woocommerce-breadcrumb { display:none !important; }
```

Enjoy.!

Comment: this is rule to hide all breadcrumbs, but I want to hide current crumb (only last crumb)

Comment: pls add Your breadcrumbs code  using inspect element.after class woocommerce-breadcrumb.

Comment: There is no "my breadcrumbs code", there is only default wordpress breadcrumbs and woocommerce class-wc-breadcrumb.php And there is no special class for last breadcrumb to hide text by css "display:none" All breadcrums showed as list in 'li' tags without any classes.

Comment: Try this ` .woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb li:last-child { display:none !important; }`